# How to handle array of pics in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array called rectimgs which contains about 2000 pics and to see individual pic
I do

```
  imshow(rectimgs{375}) // this displays the 375th pic in the array.
```

Now each pic is 86 * 86 * 3 (RGB)

```
   size((rectimgs{375}))

   ans =

   86    86     3
```

How do I access each pixel of a image from this array, for example I want to find out the average value for the pixel 43*44 for each picture (say Red value), How can I do that.

Comment: Can you upload a `.mat` file with the data in it so we can have a play?

Comment: Find it here   http://www.ryanmwhite.com/research/attractiveness_data.zip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out for eg: to access Green value for pixel 86 * 86 of 456th picture

```
rectimgs{456}(86,86,3)
```

will work

Comment: For straightening out and getting the individual values into matrices   `for i = 1:2253
  for j = 1:86
    for k = 1:86
      red(i,((j-1)*86)+k)   =   rectimgs{i}(j,k,1);
      green(i,((j-1)*86)+k) = rectimgs{i}(j,k,2);
      blue(i,((j-1)*86)+k)  =  rectimgs{i}(j,k,3); 
    end
  end
end `